# htaccess - How to allow access only to static files for specific domain

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, cdn

The idea is to serve js,css, img files using different domains so I created following domains:

- css.mydomain.com
- js.mydomain.com
- img.mydomain.com

The main site URL is www.mydomain.com. When I access the site throw main URL every img,css,js files are delivered to user throw subodomains. And that everything works fine.

**PROBLEM IS** that I can access main site using one of domains css.mydomain.com, js.mydomain.com, img.mydomain.com

AND I want is to deny every request that is not js, css, img file type.

**How can I do this over htaccess?**

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd answer this since I ran into the same issue.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^css.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(?:css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^js.mydomain.com $ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(?:js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

So the first line checks the host against the matching string (case-insensitive).

Second line checks whether the requested file DOES NOT match an allowed extension (so you can change the allowed extensions by adding or removing - separated by a pipe). "?:" in regex is a non-capturing group match.

Third line sets the response to Forbidden should the request NOT match the allowed extensions in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using <files>. This is explained fairly well here:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess.html

You can first deny everything and then allow just those file types you want.

Comment: Thanks for replay. How to do this only for this domains: css.mydomain.com   js.mydomain.com   img.mydomain.com

Comment: The easiest thing to do is put it in the .htaccess file in the directory that corresponds with each subdomain.